# C# listview count >0 but has no items how is this possible?

Tags: c#, listview, runtime-error, listviewitem

Perplexed by this listview object yet again. My code is kicking out a "subscript out of bounds" error when I try to retrieve the selected listviewitem from a listview in a windows form. Using the VS add watch command I see the following When I look at the watch of the listview object I see the following

```
this.SearchResults  {System.Windows.Forms.ListView, Items.Count: 52, Items[0]: ListViewItem: {0}}   System.Windows.Forms.ListView
```

So I see the count of  52 which is correct and when the program is running I am able to select a row from the collection. For example say I pick the 5th item from the collection. The Watch will return the following

```
this.SearchResults.SelectedIndices[0]   5   int
```

So with the index I want to pass out the listviewitem only to another object for further processing. When I try this I get a runtime error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '5' is not valid for 'index'.
```

How is this possible? I have 52 items and the code is behaving as if the listview is empty it seems. I have tried hardcoding an index and that did not work either.

My code for the constructor for this form the listview is below

```
public ResultsDisplay(List<MATS_Doc> foundDocs)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.CenterToScreen();
        this.SearchResults.Columns.Add("Title");
        this.SearchResults.Columns.Add("Stuff");
        foreach (MATS_Doc doc in foundDocs)
        {
            // retrieve coresponding document
            // create new ListViewItem
            ListViewItem searchResults = new ListViewItem(doc.Id.ToString());
            searchResults.SubItems.Add(doc.Title);
            searchResults.SubItems.Add(doc.Stuff);
            // add the listviewitem to a new row of the ListView control
            this.SearchResults.Items.Add(searchResults); //show Text1 in column1, Text2 in col2
        }
        foreach (ColumnHeader column in this.SearchResults.Columns)
        {
            column.Width = -2;
        }
        this.Show();
    }
```

***UPDATE***

below is the code where the exception is thrown. The listview is in the same form

```
 if (scoredListing == null)
        {
            DocumentView showdoc = new DocumentView(this.SearchResults.SelectedItems[this.SearchResults.SelectedIndices[0]]);
            showdoc.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: can you give us more code to see how this List is initialized, or how the Property looks like?

Comment: I don't understand the line where you say you select the 5th item... It looks like your trying to select the 5th _selected_ item, not item.

Comment: I am curious to see the code where you 'paste' the listviewitem

Comment: Please post the code that throws your exception. An exception alone doesn't help us detect anything. Or, how GlaDOS would say: *It doesn't help us, help you, help us, help us all* ;)

Comment: I updated the post with the offending line. I am launching another form and I am trying to pass out the listviewitem using the SelectedItems field.

Comment: @TheCodeNovice I wrote an answer that takes your update into consideration. I hope the answer is useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with:

```
this.SearchResults.SelectedItems[this.SearchResults.SelectedIndices[0]]
```

which should be this instead:

```
this.SearchResults.Items[this.SearchResults.SelectedIndices[0]]
```

If you only have selected 1 item, `SelectedItems` will only hold 1 element and will throw an exception, if you try to access an index other than `0`

Answer (score 3):

```
this.SearchResults.SelectedIndices[0]
```

will throw every time when you have no selection, as `SelectedIndices` is empty so there is no first element. What is the value of `this.SearchResults.SelectedIndices.Count`? Your index must be between 0 and this value - 1.

EDIT: OK, found this in [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.selected%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Beware of never-shown lists
>
> The Selected property cannot be trusted if your ListView has never
>   been drawn (for example, it's in a TabControl, in a tab that has not
>   been selected yet). In that case, the SelectedItems and
>   SelectedIndices of the parent ListView are not correctly updated and
>   will still be empty.

EDIT2: which was interesting but unrelated. As @nolonar notes, `SelectedIndices` contain indices in reference to all items, not selected items, so value 5 doesn't refer to fifth select item (as there is maybe only one) but to fifth item overall.

Comment: I think he's selecting the 5th item, which then throws an exception. Though I'm not sure. This question is extremely confusing, tbh...

Comment: You are right, I was also not sure, as shown syntax is unclear.

Comment: I have not added any error catching as of yet, but I am 100% positive I have something selected. When I use the VS Watch i see that it evalutates correctly to the coresponding row I picked. MY issue is I cannot use that int value in the selecteditems field to extract back out the listviewitem. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: What is the value od `SelectedItems.Count`?

Answer (score 2):

you may need to use

```
this.SearchResults.Items[4]
```

to select 5th item.

when you use `SelectedItems` of the list it returns only the selected items. in the selected item collection 5th item may not be there when you call it. because there may not any selection or only one item can be selected at ones.

Comment: I am not sure why but this worked. I am confused why .SelectedItems would throw and exception but .Items would not in this instance in any event thanks for the suggestion. Blew over an hour on this one.

Comment: See @nolonar's answer which is correct explanation of the problem